# get ElementRef.nativeElement width properties from component after data injection

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I have a component provided by an external Angular component library which is a private open-source project for the company I work for. The component has it's content injected into it from an Observable, and this data is not available at the initial render. The component in question is a Data Table Cell, part of a larger Data Table, much like the [Material data table](https://material.io/design/components/data-tables.html#usage).

One of these cells has a long string that, depending on the data that is returned from the API, may overflow from the container. In this case, I need to shorten the string by chopping the middle out and replacing it with '...'. The string is a file path, e.g 'C:\really\really\really\really\really\long\path\to\file.txt'. Say the overflow was hidden from the '\path\to\file.txt' section, I would want the middle chopped out like so: 'C:\really\really...\long\path\to\file.txt'. This is similar to how macOS handles long file paths in Finder. I can do this fine, using a Pipe, however I'm unsure how to get the width of the component. I have tried using a ViewChild, like this:

```
@ViewChild('path') public path: ElementRef;
```

However, when I look at the measurement properties in the `path.nativeElement` object, they're all 0 - for example:

```
scrollHeight: 0
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 0
```

I think this is because the data is injected into the table after the load. I have tried looking at the `path` variable in `ngAfterViewInit`, and it's getting the right component, but the innerHTML, text, content attributes are all empty. How would I get the most recent version of this variable?

Alternatively, if you have any other suggestions for how I could achieve this, that would be excellent. Thank you.

EDIT: Some updates. I have now got two options: I can use a Pipe in the HTML, and send the path ElementRef to the pipe, like this:

```
<div #path>{{ value | truncate: path }}</div>
```

And the Pipe code looks like this:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'truncate' })
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  public transform(value: string, element: any): string {
    const { scrollWidth, clientWidth } = element;
    // computation to figure out what the value of the new string should be
    return value;
  }

}
```

The element has the un-truncated value in, but the scrollWidth and the clientWidth are equal, which is incorrect when the value is too long for the container (so it overflows); the scrollWidth should be longer than the clientWidth. This means I cannot compute how many characters should be truncated, as the pipe has no idea how far it's overflowing. I think the reason for these two variables being the same value is that the data has not yet been injected, so the element (a div, so a block element) is taking up the width of it's container. If I inspect the element after, I can see that scrollWidth is larger than the clientWidth.

The other way I've tried is to use a proxy function in my component class, which then returns the value from the pipe, like this:

```
public truncatePath(value: string, element: any) {
  return new TruncatePipe().transform(value, element);
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div #path>{{ truncatePath(value, path) }}</div>
```

This works (clientWidth and scrollWidth are different), but it repeatedly runs the function, which is obviously hindering performance of the application.

EDIT 2: if I put the pipe code in a `setTimeout`, the clientWidth is the correct value and the string gets truncated, however as it's in the setTimeout it doesn't render that string.

Comment: I have deleted my answer since it was related to fetching the styles of an element rather than dom properties. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this, using the Pipe. Here is my code:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'truncate' })
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  public transform(value: string, element: any): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable<string>((observer: Observer<string>) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const { scrollWidth, clientWidth } = element;
        if (scrollWidth > clientWidth) {
          const avgCharWidth = Math.floor(scrollWidth / value.length);
          const middleOfString = Math.floor(value.length / 2);
          const numberToRemove = Math.ceil((scrollWidth - clientWidth) / avgCharWidth) + 1;
          const parts = [
            value.slice(0, middleOfString - (numberToRemove / 2)),
            '&#8230;',
            value.slice(middleOfString + (numberToRemove / 2))
          ];
          observer.next(parts.join(''));
        }
      });
      observer.next(value);
    });
  }

}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div #path [innerHTML]="value | truncate:path | async"></div>
```

Some notes:

- The pipe returns the value outside of the `setTimeout`, as otherwise the element has not been rendered once and so has no DOM attributes. It then runs again and checks that the initial value does not overflow, and if it does, computes the new string with the '...' in the middle. This does mean that the Pipe is run twice for each value, which could get quite expensive with 100s of rows, but I see of no other way of doing it right now.
- The `AsyncPipe` renders the latest value from the Observable
- It needs to be inside a setTimeout so that it's rendering is in a separate process

The results:

- Original string: C:\really\really\really\really\long\path\to\file1.txt (overflows container)
- Truncated string: C:\really\really\real…long\path\to\file1.txt
- Process: Pipe is run once, and the original value returns. The setTimeout code then runs, finds that the original string overflows and computes the new string. The async pipe updates the value in the rendering.

--

- Original string: C:\path\to\file1.txt (fits into container)
- Truncated string: C:\path\to\file1.txt
- Process: The Pipe is run once, returns the original value. The setTimeout code runs, find the original string string does not overflow and so doesn't go any further.

I'd be very interested to know if there are further ways to improve this so that the Pipe doesn't need to run twice, and also a way to remove the setTimeout would be fantastic too.